# LARAVEL 5.7 FPDF - Config file to change orientation of PDF is not working

Tags: fpdf, laravel-5.7

I'm using Laravel 5.7 on my application and I installed codedge/laravel-fpdf to create PDF files. The installation was successful and I was able to generate PDF file with their sample on the documentation:

```
Fpdf::AddPage();
Fpdf::SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
Fpdf::Output();
exit();
```

However, I want to change the paper size and page orientation. So I run:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider" --tag=config
```

and it generates config file at config/fpdf.php

When I try to change the orientation and size it doesn't work.

```
'orientation'   => 'L',
'unit'          => 'mm',
'size'          => 'Letter',
```

What could be the possible reason to this?

Comment: can you please try below code. I didn't test it.
Please create a constructor Fpdf class.

`$pdf = new Fpdf('L', 'mm', 'letter');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
$pdf->Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
$pdf->Output();
exit();`

Comment: It doesn't work on Laravel. But I try that before on a native php application. and It works..

Comment: I have updated the answer. please check it

Answer (score 0):

I did like below code. It's working. what you have to do, you can create a class to extend FPDF.

**Class Name: *class.custom.print.php*. you can keep file location where you want.**

```
use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf;

class customPdf extends Fpdf
{
    public function Header()
    {
        //you can add your own code
    }
    public function Footer()
    {
        //you can add your own code
    }

}
```

You can add a function in *your Controller*.

```
require_once 'class.custom.print.php';

$objPdf = new customPdf('L', 'mm', 'A4');
$objPdf->SetTitle("Title");
$objPdf->SetAuthor('Author');
$objPdf->AddPage();
$objPdf->AliasNbPages();
ob_start();
$objPdf->Output("Title.pdf", 'I');
ob_flush();
exit;
```

If you are getting any difficulties, please let me know.